# iOS multi module application

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store

Is it possible  to create a business application (not public, like other public application in the app store) which will have a multiple dynamic  modules, i don't want to keep this modules inside the app, instead i want to download it through network based on user role,  save it on file system  and load it dynamically, and for next time load it from file system. Is it possible also to use a In app purchase to take some fee for this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS security model is designed to prevent you from executing code that was downloaded off the internet. Windows/Mac/Linux have had huge security problems because of their ability to execute any code presented to them, and iOS is designed from the ground up to prevent it.

Jail breaking completely disables all that security, and if you have an Enterprise developer account you'll be able to punch a few very small holes in it...

But generally, no — what you're trying to do is not possible unless the modules are written in javascript and executed by the built in WebKit engine.

You'll just need to compile it into the app. If you've got an enterprise account, then you can check for a new version on every launch and force the user to install the latest version before they can use it (create an xml file describing the new version and with a URL to the actual ipa file, tell the system to open the URL to the xml file, the user will be asked to confirm the app install, and then it will install itself).

With regard to in-app purchases, I don't think so. You'll just have to set a price low enough nobody will hesitate to buy it twice.